# React native invariant violation element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am following a tutorial and i am facing with this error.

> Invariant Violation:Element type is invalid expected a string but got 
>   object:
>   Check the render method of 'Home'
>   This error is located at:
>
> in Home(at index.js:12)

This is my file structure:

[image: File structure]

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import Home from './screens/Home';

EStyleSheet.build({
    $primaryBlue:'#4F6D7A',
    $white:'#fff'    
});

export default ()=> <Home/>;
```

home.js:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Container from '../components/Container';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import InputWithButton from '../components/TextInput';

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
       return (
          <Container>
             <StatusBar translucent={false} barStyle="light-content"> 
             </StatusBar>
             <Logo/>
             <InputWithButton/>
             <InputWithButton/>
          </Container>            
        );   
    }    
}

export default Home;
```

Container.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const Container = ({children})=>(
   <View style = {styles.Container}>
      {children}
   </View>
);

Container.propTypes={
   children:PropTypes.any,
};
export default Container;
```

Comment: Change your export of `Container`, it will be `import Container from ...`

Comment: hi should i change home.js's import {Container} to import Container ? tried didnt work

Comment: error locations about container is gone actually.only in Home(at index.js:12 ) exist i updated question